# best practice for actions in MVC folder structure and use-cases

Tags: model-view-controller

I have an MVC project following the screaming architect pattern with use-cases folder structure.
I'm building a website where customers can for example attend to a online-class. The admin is handling all the creation, editing and deletion for the classes, and a customer can attend to a class and cancel their attendants.

My question is should all the class-relevant actions (both for customers and admins) go into the classController independently or should it be separated?

My project is much bigger than this and I find it pretty massive to sort everything relevant to ex. Class in one controller, so therefore I made a "adminClassController" for all the admin actions and the customers class actions is in the regular classController together with the index view for the classes.

Is this a bad practice or doesn't it matter?